# TableViewController crashes when calling a retained property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tableview

I have a Table View Controller and during its initialisation I set an NSArray property which is then used in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to display the data on the table.

But, when I touch a row, once I call this retained NSArray property it says EXC_BAD_ACCESS!

FYI the property is defined as shown below, and uses a custom getter function:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *dataList;
```

and in the .m file:

```
@synthesize dataList;

- (NSArray *)dataList
{
    if (!dataList)
    {
        NSString *p = [kind lowercaseString];
        NSString *s = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:p ofType:@"txt"];
        NSLog(@"%@",s);

        NSData *dataRep = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:s];
        NSPropertyListFormat format;
        dataList = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData: dataRep
                                                     mutabilityOption: NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                               format: &format
                                                     errorDescription: nil];
        if (dataList.count == 0)
            NSLog(@"Fetch failed!");
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post more code? Such as your custom getter function?

Comment: You need to post more code here. Either you have an overridden getter/setter, or you're mis-handling the array's retain count elsewhere.

Comment: You may also wish to turn that into a copy property instead. This means if you assign an NSMutableArray to the property, then mutate the array, the property's version of the array will not be mutated. If you assign a non-mutable NSArray instead, the copy will act just like retain.

Comment: Hi thank you for your responses! I just posted my getter function, please have a look. I also tried 'Copy' but it didn't do any difference.

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
dataList = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData ...
```

This function does not begin with `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain`, therefore it returns an autoreleased object. However, you need it to be retained so that it stays around.

You have two options:

```
self.dataList = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData ...
```

or,

```
dataList = [[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData ...] retain];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand your point completely, though none of those worked =( I think I'll work around it by copying its value to another NSArray by the time it is set. A great question of mine, what's the difference between the calls: myProperty and self.myProperty ?

Comment: That's part of the important part. `myProperty` is accessing the instance variable *directly*, while `self.myProperty` is going through the synthesized (or your custom) getter/setter methods. In particular, when you use `@property (retain)` and `@synthesize`, assigning a value with `self.myProperty = ...` will automatically retain that object. However, in your custom method here, you're assigning an autoreleased object directly to the instance variable. You need to retain it first.